# Android FastAdapter ClickEventHook isn't working properly

Tags: android, kotlin, button, fastadapter

I am seeking forgiveness for this simple problem. I am using [FastAdapter](https://github.com/mikepenz/FastAdapter) for the first time and I am new to Kotlin.
Let me share the problem.
I have a layout for the recyclerview item holder, an adapter which extends **AbstractItem** class.

Actually I couldn't format the code correctly here on Stack overflow. So I created the code at GitHub Gist. Here is the [link](https://gist.github.com/jobayer/bb04bdafe9ef2caf0b81599a80551b21).

In the `layout_add_item.xml` file, I have two buttons, one's id is `addStudent` and another one's id is `addTeacher`.

So, my problem is, these two button's onClickListener is not triggered until I click on the root layout once on every onCreate method is called. If I click on the LinearLayout once, then these two button's onClickEvent get fired normally.

I don't know what's wrong here :-(

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The concept behind the `EventHook` system exposed in the `FastAdapter` is meant to ensure listeners are not loosely re-attached everytime the data gets bound to the item, or even worse to introduce memory leaks.

The API itself due to that tries to prevent those various aspects.

Using Kotlin the `FastAdapter` exposes a method which should simplify this setup procedure some more for you.

For example:

```
mFastAdapter.addClickListener({ vh: SimpleImageItem.ViewHolder -> vh.imageView }) { view, position, fastAdapter, item ->
   // react on the click on the `imageView` of the `SimpleImageItem.ViewHolder`            
}
```